# SeekBar inside ListView recycling issue

Tags: android, listview, textview, baseadapter, seekbar

I am having problem with my SeekBar and TextView inside ListView. It works good when user moves SeekBar (it updates TextView in corresponding row as SeekBar progress is changing for the same row).

The problem is with the ListView recycling views. When fast scrolling, all rows are getting crazy. I found some solutions with ViewHolder and tried to implement it, but I wasn't successful (it still doesn't work).

Here is my Custom adapter that extends BaseAdapter

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SimpleListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    //private TextView tvDrink, tvPrice, tvQuantity;
    //private ImageView imgV;
    //private SeekBar seeker;
    private List<Menu> list;

    private ViewHolder holder;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Activity activity;

    public SimpleListAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Menu> list){
        this.activity = a;
        this.list = list;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if(v == null){
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tvDrink = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.drink);
            holder.tvPrice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.price);
            holder.seeker = (SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.seek);
            //imgV = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);

            v.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
        Menu m = list.get(position);

        holder.tvDrink.setText(m.getDrink());
        holder.tvPrice.setText(m.getPrice());

        holder.seeker.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekerListener());

        return v;
    }

    private class SeekerListener implements OnSeekBarChangeListener{


        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {


                View view = (View) seekBar.getParent().getParent();
                holder.tvQuantity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.quantitiy);
                holder.tvQuantity.setText(""+progress);

            //  seeker.setTag(tvQuantity);
            //  tvQuantity.setTag(seeker);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            //notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        TextView tvDrink;
        TextView tvPrice;
        TextView tvQuantity;
        SeekBar seeker;
    }
}
```

P.S. Later on I will add ImageView, but I don't have problem with that since I am using external library for handling image caching inside listview.

Comment: You will need to save the progress of the `SeekBar` in each row upon change, and reset it from `getView()`.

Comment: Can you provide some code, please? How to save the progress in each row?

Comment: You can save the progress from the `OnSeekBarChangeListener` callback method. As for the code, please try implementing it yourself, and post a question if you run into any issues.

Comment: Look, I know what I have to do all the time and I know where to do it. I know that I have to save it but my problem is how. Should I put it in sqlite, in shared preferences, in hashmap, in some kind of a object etc... That's what I need to know.

Comment: Save it in a local position-based int array